# How to construct $F_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$ quotient ring and check whether it is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Could you please suggest me methods for constructing this kind of quotient rings and checking if they are field. For example, if we show that $(x^3+x^2+1)$ is irreducible, then does this imply that $F_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$ is a field. 
  Could you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But $x^3+x^2+1$ *is* irreducible. Otherwise, it would be possible to express it as the product of two non-constant polynomials, one of which had to be of degree $1$ (since $x^3+x^2+1$ has degree $3$). But then it would have a root in $\mathbb{F}_2$, which is not the case.

Comment: What about construction? How to construct $F_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+1)$ quotient ring?

Comment: @ArmenGabrielyan What about it? As usual, $\bigl(p(x)+(x^3+x^2+1)\bigr)+\bigl(q(x)+(x^3+x^2+1)\bigr)=p(x)+q(x)+(x^3+x^2+1)$ and $\bigl(p(x)+(x^3+x^2+1)\bigr).\bigl(q(x)+(x^3+x^2+1)\bigr)=p(x)q(x)+(x^3+x^2+1)$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think I just misunderstood what construction means in this context.

Comment: Thank you that was really useful!

Answer (score 1):

Fact 1: $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, as the polynomial ring over a base field.

Fact 2: By the logic in José's answer, $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible.

Fact 3: The quotient of a ring by a maximal ideal gives a field.

These allow you to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! If p(x) is irreducible then the ideal it  generates will be a maximal ideal in F[x] where F is a field. And we have a well known result that  R/I is a field iff I is maximal . 
hence the result

Hope it works